# JavaScript ES6 promise with Angular2 - undefined variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ecmascript-6

I have any array of objects as shown below:

```
let PAGES = [
  new BasePage(
    'home',
    'test')
];

let pagesPromise = Promise.resolve(PAGES);
```

I'm now trying to return a `BasePage` object by calling the method below.

```
getPageByPage(name: string): BasePage {

  let page: BasePage;

  pagesPromise.
     then(pages => page = pages.find(p => p.name === name));

  return page;

}
```

The variable `page` is undefined - I'm not sure how to get around this. Furthermore, I'm also not sure if I'm abusing the promise principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return page` gets executed before the resolution of the pagesPromise.  The variable `page` will only contain the result of the .find in the resolution function that called it...

```
  pagesPromise.
    then(pages => page = pages.find(p => p.name === name)).
    then(() => console.log(page));
```